# Stationary mailtemplate imagetags not working

Tags: android, html, css, email

I've made a stationary template for the Mail.app on mac for a client. Everything seems to work fine, but when I test the mail the social media icons don't seem to work. All images have been made retina and the mail works on iPhone/iPad, desktop etc perfectly.

You can download the mail template over here:
[Downloadlink](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=35980841368930284132)

This is the code that isn't working:

```
                <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA start -->
            <table class="row">
              <tr>
                <td class="wrapper last">
                  <table class="twelve collumns">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <a class="social" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Arts-Square/163268623774158" id="B449597F-84AE-4E27-B114-41646952565D"><img src="facebook.png" width="45" height="16"/></a>
                        <a class="social" href="http://www.linkedin.com/company/arts-square" id="B449597F-84AE-4E27-B114-41646952565D"><img src="linkedin.png" width="45" height="16"/></a>
                        <a class="social" href="http://www.twitter.com/ArtsSquare" id="B449597F-84AE-4E27-B114-41646952565D"><img src="twitter.png" width="45" height="16"/></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- SOCIAL MEDIA end -->
```

The css:

```
.social{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 25px;
   width: 45px;
   height: 16px;
 }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your images online. Something like this:

```
<img src="http://www.yoursite.com/images/placed/here.png" width="45" height="16"/>
```

Because you have relative links, they will only work in relation to where you view the html. Because the html is sent as an email, there is no way to point someone to a `facebook.png` image located in the same folder.

Comment: It's a stationary package (you should download the attachment I've putted in the first post). That's a folder with the images embedded, especially for relative paths. All the images are stored in there. All the other images (logo.png et cetera) are working fine. Only the 3 anchortags with their image inside don't.

Comment: I can only comment on how the email html arrives in an inbox. If the image links within the anchors are absolute when they arrive in the recipients email, they should obviously work. See if you can find a way to check the html source from there, it could reveal the issue further up the process.